# Creating controller classes in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing an accounts related project using spring mvc. I have problem in creating controller classes. Like Action class in struts framework do we need to create separate controller for spring ie (individual controller for every UI pages). I stuck up here. How can I create a controller class? based on module or by UI pages?

Comment: I have provided a generic solution to your question. If you have any specific query please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, You want to know the design of serving request.  It is not necessary or a good practice to create controller for serving each request(page). I think you should go for module based controllers. You can follow [MVC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/basic_mvc_architecture.htm) architecture to have a better understanding on coupling requests with controllers.Spring have mvc support. There are numerous tutorials in spring mvc.

Here is a [demo](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-annotation-example/) of spring MVC.